# Spring boot, resolving already resolved views

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

Im trying to get the basic spring-boot jsp sample to work.

The problem is that i keep on getting a 404 error.
In the log i can see that the controller is being called and that it returns the correct jsp view.

But then the DispatcherServlet is trying to find a controller for the jsp.

The log:

```
2014-07-22 13:00:18.262 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
2014-07-22 13:00:18.264 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public java.lang.String sample.jsp.WelcomeController.welcome(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)]
2014-07-22 13:00:18.265 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
2014-07-22 13:00:18.279 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'welcome'; URL [welcome]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-07-22 13:00:18.279 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'time' of type [java.util.Date] to request in view with name 'welcome'
2014-07-22 13:00:18.279 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Added model object 'message' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'welcome'
2014-07-22 13:00:18.282 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [welcome] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
2014-07-22 13:00:18.285 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/welcome]
2014-07-22 13:00:18.286 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /welcome
2014-07-22 13:00:18.288 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/welcome]
2014-07-22 13:00:18.289  WARN 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2014-07-22 13:00:18.289 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2014-07-22 13:00:18.289 DEBUG 4716 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

The code im using is the sample code from the spring-boot samples:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's caused by [a bug in Spring 4.1 snapshots](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12013) which is what Boot's master branch uses. Until that bug's fixed, you should use an earlier version of the sample, for example the [latest release (1.1.4)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp).

Comment: Tnx, changing it to 1.1.4 did stop the double resolving. However Im still not getting my view because the spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp in my application.properties doesn''t seem to be used.



Now im getting a "Could not resolve view with name 'welcome' in servlet" error